# How's my Warlock and Endgame Plan?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, warlock

My race is Variant Human with the Actor perk and 20 Charisma, and I’m proficient in Arcana, Persuasion, Intimidation, Deception and Sleight of Hand. My Patron is a Great Old One and at level 3 I’m taking Pact of the Tome, as well as swapping out one of the Eldritch Invocations I’ll have obtained at level 2 for “Book of Ancient Secrets” which’ll let me get the Find Familiar spell. My background is Charlatan, giving me the False Identity feature (my false identity is a Noble) and proficiency with disguise kits and forgery tools. At level 4 I’m going to take the Lucky feat, which should make all of this a little easier.

My familiar will be a spider, which'll be important later on. Spiders are the smallest familiars in the list and arguably the least conspicuous, making them ideal spies. Even if someone sees it, unless they’re able to detect celestials/fiends/fey the worst that can happen is it gets crushed and I have to drop 10 gold to re-summon it.

Now at a later point in the campaign, around level 14, I'm going to try and secure an audience with the King - most likely through a mix of heroic acts and cozying up with nobles. Why level 14 you might ask? Create Thrall.

"At 14th level, you gain the ability to infect a humanoid’s mind with the alien magic of your patron. You can use your action to touch an incapacitated humanoid. That creature is then charmed by you until a remove curse spell is cast on it, the charmed condition is removed from it, or you use this feature again. You can communicate telepathically with the charmed creature as long as the two of you are on the same plane of existence."

Now Create Thrall only works on incapacitated humanoids, and I'm not about to attack the King. That's where my familiar comes in. If I can secure an audience with the King and be considered his guest, then with some luck and a few stealth checks I should be able to get my familiar access to the King's chambers, where it'll wait for him to go to sleep.

I've cleared this with my DM and he agrees that, so long as they aren't woken up, a sleeping target can count as incapacitated. And as it should happen, players can cast touch spells through their familiars.

If all goes well, I should be able to make the King my thrall. Using the Actor feat I took at the start, along with a disguise kit to make me look the part, I’m going to have the King pronounce me his long lost son and heir to the throne. Ideally I’d also like to have him fall to some tragic accident and free up the spot for a new Thrall, preferably a more combat-focused one this time. As a Great Old One Warlock I’ll also have access to the Detect Thoughts spell, which’ll hopefully help prevent me from being overthrown in case the DM plans anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions? This is actually only my second time playing D&D, first time playing a warlock, and my first campaign didn’t last very long. Is there any equipment that might help? Other perks I should take? Spells? And how is this as a game plan in general? I’m pretty sure the DM will allow it since it’ll be pretty late game

Comment: You've buried the lead. That's a lot of text to get through with no idwa why until very late in the game.

Comment: If you want to ask this question in a way that we can help, consider asking how you survive to lvl 14 so that you can put this usurping of the throne into action.  Also, Welcome, please take the [tour] to get an idea of what this site has to offer. (And I like the way you think ...)

Comment: This question seems better suited for a forum rather than a Q&A site like this one. [Here are some forum suggestions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/24817). As for my opinion: your plan seems pretty cool and well thought out, but lvl14 is far away. You're gonna have to accept the fact that your plan may end up not feasible by the time you reach that level (being wanted dead or alive, anarchy due to a cataclysmic event, being in a different plane altogether...)

Comment: If you feel like you can rephrase your question to better suit this site, please do [take the tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). Also, check out the [help page](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for topics related to asking questions.

Comment: In a world with Charm effects, regularly hitting the leadership with Remove Curse (especially when they do something like pronounce a newly arrived stranger is a long lost child and heir) will be a thing.

Comment: While I agree this is entirely opinion-based, I love it and really enjoy when players think like this.